# Extração de informações com Python

Tags: python, windows

Estou realizando alguns testes com `Python` e gostaria de extrair alguns dados que são apresentados na página de "**Informações do sistema**" no *Windows*.

Sei que a biblioteca "`os`" do `Python` permite que executemos processos como este, que é o `msinfo32`.

Gostaria de uma orientação sobre como extrair os dados de por exemplo, o campo "**Processador**" e "**Produto BaseBoard**". Qual seria os melhores recursos ou bibliotecas para enviar essas informações como uma `string`, por exemplo?

Estou usando `Python 3.7.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a biblioteca `platform` para pegar essas informações do sistema.

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.machine()
'x86'
>>> platform.version()
'5.1.2600'
>>> platform.platform()
'Windows-XP-5.1.2600-SP2'
>>> platform.uname()
('Windows', 'name', 'XP', '5.1.2600', 'x86', 'x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel')
>>> platform.system()
'Windows'
>>> platform.processor()
'x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel'
```

Na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html) você vai encontrar mais informações sobre ela.

Se precisar de informações sobre processos e utilização do sistema, tem também a biblioteca `psutil`.

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.cpu_count()
4
```

De novo, você vai encontrar mais detalhes na [documentação](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

É possível também usar a biblioteca `os` para obter outras informações do sistema que você consegue pela linha de comando. Faça o teste:

```
import os
for line in os.popen('systeminfo'): print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: Já havia feito alguns testes com essa biblioteca também, mas se eu precisasse especificamente das informações contidas no msinfo32, haveria alguma forma?

Comment: Tem informações que você consegue com um 'systeminfo'. Vou colocar na resposta. Se precisar de algo mais específico, diga o que é que podemos ajudar.